# how do I log a Jersey2 Http request?

Tags: jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have code like:

```
Client client = configuration.getClient();
client.register(new LoggingFilter());

return client.target(URL)
       .queryParam(LOGIN_NAME, "XXXX")
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .get(AsiAccounts.class);
```

However, I get no details on what is actually happening. How can I get Jersey client to provide more detailed output to determine the source of the problem?

Comment: The only thing more you're going to get from the logging filter is the body of the request/response. Other than that, you will need to say exactly what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: If you want to see the body use `new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true)`.